# page not loading properly while recording https protocol in jmeter

Tags: https, jmeter

I'm trying to record an application with https protocol in jmeter.

Requests are being captured in JMeter, the However web page is not loading properly.In the web, responses are coming in a line where I cannot proceed further.

I'm able to record HTTP protocol without any problem.

help on this would be really appreciable.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you start [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) for the first time, JMeter will create a Certificat Authority in jmeter/bin folder named:

- ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt

You need to add it to your browser (Firefox for example) following the instructions in paragraph:

> Installing the JMeter CA certificate for HTTPS recording

Once done, you'll be able to correctly record HTTPS traffic.

Comment: Thanks a lot @UBIK.. Now it works fine for me in Mozilla firefox, But In chrome im still facing the same problem even after installing the certificate.Can you kindly help me in this.